# Access VirtualBox Mac OS guest on Windows 10 host network

Tags: windows, macos, networking

I have a windows 10 host with the IP address like 192.168.8.101, subnet mask as 255.255.255.0 and gateway as 192.168.8.1.

I have also installed Mac OS Sierra on VirtualBox on this windows host. This guest mac os has IP like 10.0.2.15 and gateway as 192.168.8.1.

The internet of my windows host is working fine on my guest mac os.

However, the guest is not accessible on windows host. I can't find the mac os in windows network, or can access it using IP address etc.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have got it....as I'm on virtualbox, I have to set my network adapter setting to bridge adapter instead of NAT. After setting to bridge adapter my guest mac os's IP has changed as well, now it looks something like 192.168.8.103 which is different than what I was getting earlier and this IP is reachable from windows host and I'm able to login remotely. This might help someone else having similar trouble and save some time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to programming; it is a configuration problem, and it belongs on [su], not [so].